# Access Me.Filter stopped working

Tags: vba, ms-access, filter

I have a realy strange problem with a filter in Access 2010.
The filter worked great for the past days but today I noticed it stopped working (filters out everything) it's a pretty simple Me.Filter. I resetted the VBA code to a state where I know it was working but it still refuses to work as expected. this is an example filter that I am using:

```
Me.Filter = (Hersteller LIKE '*Test*' OR ID LIKE '*Test*' OR Typ LIKE '*Test*' OR Nennmaß LIKE '*Test*' OR Herstellertyp LIKE '*Test*') AND Status = 'Einsetzbar' AND ID is not null
```

Of course it's activated afterwards `Me.FilterOn = True`

Seeing that I tried the my old working code it must be something that I changed in the form or the backend table. Unfortunatly I didn't change anything that I can imagin having an impact on filtering. Column names etc. are the same... What makes it wierder is that my date filter `Me.Filter = (Datum > #01/18/2015#) OR (Datum > #01/18/2015#)` works perfectly. Any idea would be appreciated!!

Comment: Check you've allowed filters in the data tab of the properties of the form and have you tried a SQL query of a similar nature, see if one of the entries is causing the nil return?

Comment: Filters are allowd, how would I go about making such an filter action via SQL in VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figuered it out! I have no idea why it worked before and not now but using * as wildcard doesn't work for my version (Access 2010) I had to change every * in my filter to a % and now it finnaly wokrs! `Me.Filter = "(Hersteller LIKE '%test%' OR ID LIKE '%test%' OR Typ LIKE '%test%' OR Nennmaß LIKE '%test%' OR Herstellertyp LIKE '%test%') AND ID is not null"`

Comment: Seems like you might be working on a .adp file, which uses the ANSI-92 standard instead of ANSI-89, which is what I am accustomed to. Typically you use the standard associated with your back end, so if you're using SQL Server you'd use ANSI-92. [See here for a full list of ANSI-92 wildcards in access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-wildcard-character-reference-af00c501-7972-40ee-8889-e18abaad12d1) Glad you worked it out!

Comment: Thats pretty much exactly what happend, i still am using a .accdb file but the option to use ANSI 92 is turned on! I just have no idea why haha but at least now I know why my code was behaving so strange....

Answer (score 1):

Notice how the last part of the code is grey? It's due to a single apostrophe outside of a string being evaluated as a comment.

Try:

```
Me.Filter = "(Hersteller LIKE '*Test*' OR ID LIKE '*Test*' OR Typ LIKE '*Test*' OR Nennmaß LIKE '*Test*' OR Herstellertyp LIKE '*Test*') AND Status = 'Einsetzbar' AND ID is not null"
```

Your current code's filter evaluates to: `(Hersteller Like`, which apparently is valid but because nothing follows the `Like`, then no records can meet the condition and no records can be returned.

The reason `Me.Filter = (Datum > #01/18/2015#) OR (Datum > #01/18/2015#)` works is because there are no apostrophes cutting off part of the clause.

Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194672.aspx):

> The Filter property is a string expression consisting of a WHERE clause without the WHERE keyword.

So anytime you are using `Me.Filter =` the following clause should be encapsulated in double quotes to ensure it evaluates as a string, which is what `.Filter` is expecting.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunatly this doesn't work... shows the same behaviour as before, no error but after the filter is being applied nothing is left.... I guess it must be some setting I have changed :(

Comment: I think it's the Stars * that don't work! The filter Me.Filter = "Status LIKE 'Test' " works but "Status LIKE '*Test*'" doesn't return any result!